# Two methods with the same code implementation

Tags: java, android

I want to know what is the best way to deal with the code below:

```java
public void hideKeyboard() {
     homePage.getDriver().navigate().back();
}

public void navigatetoPreviousPage() {
     homePage.getDriver().navigate().back();
}
```

Basically, both these codes do the same thing where it presses the android back button, but I may use the back button to hide a keyboard or the back button to move back a page.

For readability, it makes sense to have a method stating hide keyboard like after typing a field. For other scenarios, it will make sense to have a method stating I am moving back a page.

Is it ok to implement it like the above or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: I'd prefer to have multiple methods for multiple unrelated actions and if they share logic, invoke common method containing common logic from the previous wrapper method.

Comment: `homePage.getDriver().navigate().back();` code seems to be more related to name `navigatetoPreviousPage()` so put code inside this method and do something like this `public void hideKeyboard() {  navigatetoPreviousPage(); } `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's OK to implement it like this for now. What you mention yourself is important:

> For readability it makes sense to have a method stating hide keyboard like after typing a field. For other scenarios it will make sense to have a method stating I am moving back a page.

To have high-quality, maintainable code, it's important that your code expresses the intent that the programmer has with it - that will make it much easier to understand and work with for other programmers, or even for yourself in the future. So, in places in the code where you need to hide the keyboard, it's much better if you call your `hideKeyboard()` method, because it's clear and easy to understand that at that point you need to hide the keyboard; and vice versa for navigating to the previous page.

It might turn out that later, you find a better way to hide the keyboard that works in a different way than just pressing the back button. If that's the case then the only thing you'd have to do is modify the implementation of your `hideKeyboard()` method.

If you really want to avoid code duplication for now, you can just call `navigatetoPreviousPage()` inside your `hideKeyboard()` method:

```
public void hideKeyboard() {
    navigatetoPreviousPage();
}

public void navigatetoPreviousPage() {
    homePage.getDriver().navigate().back();
}
```